# Como mantener el tema de mi web en LocalStorage

Tags: javascript

Saludos tengo esté codigo que hace un toogle de clase en toda la página entre tema claro o oscuro, como podría agregar un localstorage para mantener esa clase al refrescar, gracias

```
const themeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.theme-btn');

for (let i = 0; i < themeBtn.length; i++) {

  themeBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function () {

    document.body.classList.toggle('light-theme');
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme');

    for (let i = 0; i < themeBtn.length; i++) {

      themeBtn[i].classList.toggle('light');
      themeBtn[i].classList.toggle('dark');

    }

  })

}
```

html

```
<div class="light-theme"></div>
```

gracias de antemano

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/520645/mantener-tema-oscuro-al-refrescar-y-auto-detectar-tema-del-os/520713#520713) tienes algo parecido a lo que quieres.  Extrapola el código de allí para adaptarlo al tuyo y si tienes problemas edita la pregunta con lo que hayas hecho y el problema que tengas para que podamos ayudarte (o quizás en [esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/519200/263200) sea más facil de ver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localstorage es muy simple de usar, solo asignarlo a una variable y válidas su resultado

```
    document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
          if(e.target.classList.contains('light-theme'){
            localstorage.setItem('theme','light');
          }
       
 if(e.target.classList.contains('dark-theme'){
            localstorage.setItem('theme','dark');
          }
        }
```

Y para implementarlo solo lo llamas

```
const theme = localstorage.getItem('theme');
```

Comment: ¿y que ocurre cuando aún no se ha definido por primera vez?  Es decir, cuando aun no se ha pulsado nunca el botón esa constante dará error porque no está definida en el localStorage aún tal como lo has puesto en tu respuesta

Comment: Puedes definir un tema base o preguntar al principio de la página si if(theme) y si ya existe la implementa

Comment: Si no existe ese ítem en localstorage solo veras un error por consola

Comment: Te lo decia para que mejoraras la respuesta, pues será lo siguiente que te va a preguntar el OP. No lo decia porque no lo supiera :-)

Comment: Ha vale pensé que eras la persona del post xD, estoy desde el cel ahora y modificare la respuesta gracias por el dato

Comment: @hejevero muchas gracias, me funciono tu respuesta (: saludos